# Hello World for KDE in Qtcreator

Tags: project, qt-creator, kde-plasma

I have just begun programming for KDE, the problem I face is I don't know what exactly should be the pro file for a KDE project, I have an idea for cmake though

I also tried in pro file:

LIBS += -lkdeui

I still get problem KApplication not found

Code main.cpp:

```
    #include <cstdlib>

    #include <KApplication>
    #include <KAboutData>
    #include <KCmdLineArgs>
    #include <KMessageBox>
    #include <KLocale>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        KAboutData aboutData("tutorial1",0,ki18n("Tutorial 1"),"1.0",ki18n("Displays a KMessageBox popup"),KAboutData::License_GPL,ki18n("(c) 2007"),ki18n("Some text..."),"http://example.com/","submit@bugs.kde.org");

        KCmdLineArgs::init( argc, argv, &aboutData );
        KApplication app;
        KGuiItem yesButton( i18n( "Hello" ), QString(),
                            i18n( "This is a tooltip" ),
                            i18n( "This is a WhatsThis help text." ) );
        return
            KMessageBox ::questionYesNo
            (0, i18n( "Hello World" ), i18n( "Hello" ), yesButton )
            == KMessageBox ::Yes? EXIT_SUCCESS: EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

and tutorial.pro file is:

```
    TEMPLATE = app
    CONFIG += console
    CONFIG -= qt
    SOURCES += main.cpp
    LIBS += -lkdeui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install development files for kde libraries, these are missing. I don't know which Linux distro you are using (if any) but, for example, in Debian the required package is called [kdelibs5-dev](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/kdelibs5-dev/filelist).

You will probably also need to specify the include path for these development files after installing the package. Like `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KDE`

Comment: plz give me the complete pro file contents

Comment: Try the following project file, it should work:
`TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += qt
LIBS += -lkdecore -lkdeui
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KDE
SOURCES += main.cpp`

Comment: running the code, it compiles and executes, but shows no GUI, except an empty konsole screen....

Comment: Ok, try to add line `QT += core gui widgets`, it works for me (Qt 4.8.4, KDE 4.9.5, Linux Mint 14)